# How to jump to JavaScript library source?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pycharm, webstorm

I'm using PyCharm for developing my webApp (I am from python word) and noticed: I cannot jump to react source.

For example: I want to look hot to extend Component, set cursor on `Component` press <kbd>Cmd + right mouse click</kbd> and see `cannot find declaration to go to`.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
```

Is there a way to do this or maybe there are other editors with such ability?

Update:
Seems like it works only in WebStorm but not in Pycharm. For Pycharm need load library in settings.

Comment: You need to tell WebStorm to download the library sources. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.2/configuring-javascript-libraries.html

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum thank you, but i do not see reactJs in available library. After i added custom JavaScript lib(just add reactJs from node_modules)  see no change.

Comment: React isn't written in ES6, so it has some funny properties when exporting to ES6 modules. Most people just do import React from 'react' as their import, then reference React.Component in their code. When I do that, I can put my cursor on Component in React.Component, then use Cmd-B to jump to the React code.

Comment: @PaulEveritt what redactor do you use?

Answer (score 4):

I'm able to do this using following setup:

- WebStorm -> Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> JavaScript -> JavaScript language version: ReactJS (JSX Harmony)
- Cmd + hover mouse over the library, wait until it turns blue and underlined and then (normal, left) click
- WebStorm 2016.2.3

[image: This is the state where I've just did cmd + hover. To jump to source you have to click also.]
This is the state where I've just did cmd + hover. To jump to source you have to click also.

---

[Here](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2015/10/working-with-reactjs-in-webstorm-coding-assistance/) **is the same answer from the official source**

> From there you can also jump to the component definition with Cmd-click (Ctrl+click on Windows and Linux) on component name or see a definition in a popup with Cmd-Y (Ctrl+Shift+I).

Comment: do you have in JavaScript language version ReactJs option? I have only JSX Harmony

Comment: I had JSX harmony, then updated WebStorm and now it displays as ReactJS. They should be the same.

Comment: does it work for react-router for example? And  does it show source from node_modules?

Comment: I need update Pycharm and now i see ReactJS (JSX Harmony) but still can't jump to source (

Comment: Check out my answer again  (with official source)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123281/discussion-between-tany-and-leo).